# 1px gap issue with responsive HTML template in outlook - im going crazy

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, outlook

I am creating a responsive template. Now usually for a 2 col section i always would leave a 10px gap. So a td cell that is 600px wide, would have a align="left" table set to 290px and a align="right" table set also to 290px.

But in this design im working with i have to be a bit smart about how im using background colours, and the issue is that outlook is putting a 1px gap on the right of my section even though the cell is aligned right, which shows the wrapper table background (in this case yellow). This also means it throws the divider alignment off by 1px.

Does anyone have any ideas please? Im going Crazy!!!

HTML code: http://www.codeshare.io/QrlYa

[image: screen cap of 1px issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay i figured it out! Stupid Outlook only code required on td's style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"

Code example:
http://www.codeshare.io/tQCg2